# Array manipulation based on conditions JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following array

```
0: {productid: "001", containersize: "20", ContCount: 10}
1: {productid: "002", containersize: "20", ContCount: 9}
2: {productid: "001", containersize: "40", ContCount: 4}
3: {productid: "001", containersize: "20", ContCount: 20}
4: {productid: "003", containersize: "20", ContCount: 18}
5: {productid: "001", containersize: "40", ContCount: 7}
6: {productid: "003", containersize: "40", ContCount: 25}
```

Based on this array I want to create a new array like below:

```
0: {productid: "001", containersize20: 30, containersize40: 11, total: 41}
1: {productid: "002", containersize20: 9, containersize40: 0, total: 9}
2: {productid: "003", containersize20: 18, containersize40: 25, total: 43}
```

Basically, count all the containers based on the product type and container size 20 and 40.

I have used the below code:

```
var group_to_values = data.reduce(function (obj, item) {
            obj[item.productid] = obj[item.productid] || [];
            obj[item.productid].push(item.ContCount);
            return obj;
        }, {});

        var groups = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function (key) {
            return {productid: key, ContCount: group_to_values[key]};
        });
```

But from here I'm stuck on how to move further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect fit for `reduce`. Iterate over the structure building a result object mapped to keys according to your specifications, then take the values array:

```js
const data = [
  {productid: "001", containersize: "20", ContCount: 10},
  {productid: "002", containersize: "20", ContCount: 9},
  {productid: "001", containersize: "40", ContCount: 4},
  {productid: "001", containersize: "20", ContCount: 20},
  {productid: "003", containersize: "20", ContCount: 18},
  {productid: "001", containersize: "40", ContCount: 7},
  {productid: "003", containersize: "40", ContCount: 25}
];

const res = Object.values(data.reduce((a, e) => {
  if (!(e.productid in a)) {
    a[e.productid] = {
      productid: e.productid, 
      containersize20: 0,
      containersize40: 0,
      total: 0
    };
  }
  
  a[e.productid].containersize20 += e.containersize === "20" ? e.ContCount : 0;
  a[e.productid].containersize40 += e.containersize === "40" ? e.ContCount : 0;
  a[e.productid].total += e.ContCount;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a fix on the other answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but you can achieve it in a single `.reduce` into an object indexed by `productid`, and then you can get that object's values to transform it into an array again. Don't forget to cast the `containersize` string to a number so you can add properly:

```js
const input = [
  {productid: "001", containersize: "20", ContCount: 10},
  {productid: "002", containersize: "20", ContCount: 9},
  {productid: "001", containersize: "40", ContCount: 4},
  {productid: "001", containersize: "20", ContCount: 20},
  {productid: "003", containersize: "20", ContCount: 18},
  {productid: "001", containersize: "40", ContCount: 7},
  {productid: "003", containersize: "40", ContCount: 25}
];
const output = Object.values(input.reduce((a, { productid, containersize, ContCount }) => {
  if (!a[productid]) a[productid] = {
    productid,
    total: 0,
    containersize20: 0,
    containersize40: 0,
  };
  a[productid]['containersize' + containersize] += ContCount;
  a[productid].total += ContCount;
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```

Note that none of this is jQuery, this is just plain built-in Javascript, which can often achieve things just as well as jQuery.

Comment: yes this worked but what i actually want is, for a product if  there is no containersize40 or containersize20 then i want the that object to be in the array but value would be 0 like this for example product 002 i still need containersize40 : 0

Comment: The output doesn't match OP's request.

Comment: @kevin Oh, I missed that, initialize the `-20` and `-40`s to zero when creating the object for the first time

Comment: This is still incorrect: `+= Number(containersize);` should be `+= ContCount`. You also don't need to `Number(ContCount)`--it's already a number.